# McLaurin expansion for $f(x)=e^{\sin{x}}$ of the 4:th order.

Tags: calculus

By the 4:th order, they mean using the 4:th derivative. But the differentiation gets a bit ugly quite fast, so instead of computing all the derivatives , I should be able to use the standard expansions:

$$e^t=1+t+\frac{t^2}{2!}+\frac{t^3}{3!}+B(t) \\ \sin{x}=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+B(x),$$

Where $B(t),B(x)$ are functions that are bounded close to $x=0.$ Correct me if I'm wrong, but both of the expansions above are of 4:th order since for the sine function we have two terms vanishing because they become zero?

I'm not sure how I should fuse the separate expansions of $e^t$ and $\sin{x}$ to one expansion. Setting $t=\sin{x}$ seems to give me an expression tedious tedious to work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have

$$e^t=1+t+\frac{t^2}{2!}+\frac{t^3}{3!}+\frac{t^4}{4!}+O(t^5)$$

and

$$\sin{x}=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+O(x^5),$$

So just substitute:

$$e^{\sin x} = 1 + \left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+O(x^5)\right) + \frac{1}{2!}\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+O(x^5)\right)^2 \\+ \frac{1}{3!}\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+O(x^5)\right)^3 +\frac{1}{4!}\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+O(x^5)\right)^4 + O\left(\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+O(x^5)\right)^5\right)\\
=1 + \left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}\right) + \frac{1}{2!}\left(x^2-2\frac{x^4}{3!}\right) + \frac{1}{3!}\left(x^3\right) +\frac{1}{4!}\left(x^4\right) + O\left(x^5\right).$$

Gather like terms and bob's your uncle.

$$e^{\sin x} = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!}  -\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^3}{3!} -2\frac{1}{2}\frac{x^4}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+O(x^5)\\=1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} - \frac{x^4}{8}+O(x^5).$$

Comment: How do you know that the expansion of $\sin(x)$ is of the fourth order? To me it seems that it's of third order since you have terms upp to $x^4.$

Comment: @Parseval all even degree terms in the Taylor expansion of $\sin x$ are $0$.

Comment: You make it seem so easy to gather the terms. But seriosuly, expanding something of the form $(a+b+c)^n$ for $n\geq 3$ is kind of a lot of work.

Comment: @Parseval it's easy if you count only the terms of order you care about. Consider $(x + x^3 + x^5)^3,$ and suppose I only want terms in the expansion up to order $5$. I can immediately throw away all terms involving the the $x^5$ term. Now I only need to know $(x+x^3)^3.$ How can I get a term of order 5 or lower? Well I can cube the first time. So $x^3$ is a term. I can square the first term and include the second, so $3x^5$ is a term. And that's it. Squaring the second term already gets me above $5$. So $(x + x^3 + x^5)^3=x^3+3x^5+O(x^6).$ It's actually pretty easy. Just count the degrees.

Comment: This ordo and Taylor thing feels so hokus pokus you can do what ever you like with math. "well it's a cube.. nahh don't mind it just square that thing and you'll be alright". So if you square the first and include the second, where does the 3 infront of $x^5$ come from? And why is it suddenly $x^6$ in the ordo?

Comment: @Parseval If you want two $x$'s and one $x^3$ from $(x+x^3)(x+x^3)(x+x^3),$ you can choose the two $x$'s from the first and second factor, the first and third factor, or the second and third factor. So there are three ways to choose $x\cdot x\cdot x^3$, hence the total term is $3x^5$. Altenatively look at pascal's triangle, or the binomial coefficient $3\choose 1$. And the big-O order at the end of my sum is because I included all terms up to order $5$. So terms of order $6$ and higher are what's left over. Or if you prefer weak orderings and small-o notation, $o(x^5)$ is what's left over.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another way:

$$ e^{\sin x} = e^{x}\cdot e^{-x^3/6}\cdot e^{o(x^4)} =\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^3}{6}\right)+o(x^4)$$
and the computations are now straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

ziggurism's answer is the most straightforward (using substitution), and you must master it. But here's another way: let $f=\exp\circ\sin$. Then $f'=f\times\cos$. Let $a,b,c,\ldots$ be the coefficients in the Taylor–Young expansion of $f$ at $0$:
$$f(x)\underset{x\to0}=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+ex^4+o\bigl(x^4\bigr).$$
By the way, we know that $a=1$.

We also have (since $f$ is of class $C^\infty$),
$$f'(x)\underset{x\to0}=b+2cx+3dx^2+4ex^3+o\bigl(x^3\bigr).$$

Now, writing $f\times\cos=f'$

$$\Bigl(1+bx+cx^2+dx^3+o\bigl(x^3\bigr)\Bigr)\left(1-\frac{x^2}2+o\bigl(x^3\bigr)\right)=b+2cx+3dx^2+4ex^3+o\bigl(x^3\bigr)$$
and expanding and identifying the terms with same degree (using the uniqueness of a Taylor–Young expansion) yields:

- Constant terms: $b=1$,
- Terms of degree $1$: $b=2c$, hence $c=1/2$,
- Terms of degree $2$: $c-1/2=3d$, hence $d=0$,
- Terms of degree $3$: $d-b/2=4e$, hence $e=-1/8$.

Conclusion:

$$\mathrm{e}^{\sin(x)}\underset{x\to0}=1+x+\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^4}8+o\bigl(x^4\bigr).$$

Comment: What is the difference between big ordo and small ordo? And what is class $C^{\infty}?$

Comment: @Parseval: ok, if you don't know what $o$'s are, you can safely replace all the $o(x^4)$ by $O(x^5)$ and all the $o(x^3)$ by $O(x^4)$. It doesn't change anything in this case. The class $C^\infty$ is the class of functions that you can differentiate as much as you like.

Comment: @Parseval I like to think of small-o as "strictly greater growth rate" and big-O as "greater or equal growth rate". So $o(x^4)$ is any functions of strictly greater growth rate, such as $x^{4.1}$ or $x^4\log x$, as well as $x^5$. $O(x^5)$ includes the latter but not the former. Since we have polynomials there is no distinction.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations guys! But is the notation $C^{\infty}$ a general notation or is it something you just came up with as a temporary notation?

Comment: @Parseval: [we didn't make this up!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness)

Comment: Cool, didin't know this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to find derivatives of $f(x)$ at $x=0$. 
Notice that $f'(x)= f(x)\cos(x)$ therefore $f'(0)=1$. So $f''(x) = f'(x)\cos(x)-f(x)\sin(x)$ therefore $f''(0)=1$. Then $f'''(x) = f''(x)\cos(x)-2f'(x)\sin(x)-f(x)\cos(x)$ therefore $f'''(0)=0$. And $f^{(4)}(x)=f'''(x)\cos(x)-3f''(x)\sin(x)-3f'(x) \cos(x)+ f(x)\sin(x)$. Therefore $f^{(4)}(0)=-3$. We get $f(x) = x + (x^2)/2 - (x^4)/8+ \dotsb$